# Mimic Market GUI behavior

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently updating my application to use ActionBar and Fragments. Using ActionBarSherlock I quickly created interface with pager and tabs. But I spotted a problem and I'm stuck now.

I want my app to behave similarly to Android Market - so, at first there are tabs with different fragments (I've got this) and tapping inside one of the fragments launches another fragment with different content - tabs get hidden, ActionBar remains visible.

I just can't figure out which view should be replaced, the most obvious solution to me:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.pager, newFragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Gives strange results (replaces contents of a random tab fragment). I would be glad if somebody would point me to some example, as I couldn't find any. I have to go out now, but can provide more detailed description later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I learned a few facts about Fragments and got a logical conclusion, which is an answer to this question:

- Fragments cannot contain other fragments => Pager cannot be a fragment.
- Fragments can only be replaced by other fragments (and vice versa) => I cannot replace a pager with fragment.

The solution: Create an activity with ActionBar and desired fragment (myFragment) and start it. So simple...